# Inputing & validating hex values correctly

Tags: c, validation, input, hex

I'm trying to create a simple program or function that will take the users input which could be a valid hex number.

I'm trying to work out a way to verify that it's a correct hex value and return the hex value if it's true or return an error message if it's false.

I was thinking of a function that checks every char to make sure its `0-9` or `A-F` but can't think how to implement this.

Thanks.

Comment: Is this a homework? If so, add homework tag, please.

Comment: Not homework, im trying to build my knowledge up of C , finding it very difficult as online tutoriols arent to great, and i did have a basic function working to validate input then lost all my data on my usb, i just cant seem to get it to fully validate hex

Comment: Hm.. start with simpler programs. Make sure you can understand *if*, *while* and friends, only then move on.

Comment: Got that, i started off with basic programs and managed to build up a complex program inputting data comparing,validating and error handling etc

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Given `const char *s`, if you want to determine if every character in the string pointed to by `s` is a valid hex digit you can use:

```
if (s[strspn(s, "0123456789abcdefABCDEF")] == 0)
{
    /* valid */
}
```

Comment: If every character in the _non-empty_ string.

Comment: @pmor: If the string is empty, the set of characters in the string is the empty set, and every proposition about the elements of it is vacuously true!

Comment: Many thanks! This is what I have hard time to understand: why it is "(vacuous) truth" and not "unknown"? If there are no cell phones in the room, then how can we reason whether all cell phones in the room are turned off or on, if there is no antecedent (which is the cell phones)? Another example that I've faced recently: if the test was not executed, then what is the status of it: passed or failed? I've came up to the conclusion that its status should be "unknown". Does it mean that according to the vacuous truth its status shall be passed? Can you comment on that?

Comment: @pmor: The answer to this question might help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/50873/assumption-about-elements-of-the-empty-set .  Mathematical logic doesn't have an "unknown", because that's a statement about our knowledge about the proposition, not about the truth of the proposition itself.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this (since you insist it isn't homework, I will fill in):

```
int CheckMyString(const char *aStr)
{
    const char *curr = aStr;
    while (*curr != 0)
    {
        if (('A' <= *curr && *curr <= 'F') || ('a' <= *curr && *curr <= 'f') || '0' <= *curr && *curr <= '9'))
        {
            ++curr;
        } 
        else 
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: I like this code, its validating it for a hex thats throwing me off, s if you validate for a string A-Z it would work, but getting validate for ust 0-9 A-F seems to be proven difficult

Comment: I also agree with Beginner , this must be C++ guessing this by the comment styles aswell C general uses /* */

Answer (score 1):

Adding to caf's answer using his method this function works for all radix base from **binary to base32.** You can check for valid number easily.

```
#define BINARY_BASE 2 /*Defining binary base*/
#define OCTAL_BASE 8  /*Defining octal base*/
#define DECIMAL_BASE 10 /*Defining decimal base*/
#define HEXA_BASE 16    /*Defining hexa-decimal base*/
#define BASE32_BASE 32 /*Defining base32 base*/

bool isValidNumber4Base(const char* numStr,int base)
{

    const char *validBinary = "01";
    const char *validOctal = "01234567";
    const char *validDecimal = "0123456789";
    const char *validHex = "0123456789abcdefxABCDEFX";
    const char *validBase32 = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUV";
    const char *validNumber = NULL;

    validNumber = (base == BINARY_BASE) ? validBinary : ((base == OCTAL_BASE) ? validOctal :
                    (base == DECIMAL_BASE) ? validDecimal : (base == HEXA_BASE) ? validHex : (base == BASE32_BASE) ? validBase32 : NULL);

    if(validNumber ==  NULL)
    {
        fputs("Invalid base encountered",stderr);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return (!numStr[strspn(numStr,validNumber)]) ? true : false;
}

/*Test Method For Hexa-deicmal */
int main ()
{
  char *hexa_str = "0x7FFF";    
  printf("Valid Hexa : %s\n",isValidNumber4Base(hexa_str,HEXA_BASE) == true ? "true" : "false");        
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job

```
int validate_hex(const char* hex){
  while(*hex != 0){
    if(*hex < '0' || *hex > '9')
      return 0;
    if(*hex < 'A' || *hex > 'F')
      return 0;
    hex++;
  }
  return 1;
}
```

Comment: If you're going to compare it char-by-char, then you might as well use the `isxdigit()` builtin.

Comment: This looks like it will fail. If the character is an 'A', the first test will decide it is grater then a '9' and return false incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

Just like strtod, there is [strtoul](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtoul) in the standard C library for converting from text to unsigned long.

Building on the example from your previous question:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

  unsigned int intValue;
  char *e,s[100];

  fgets(s,100,stdin); if( s[strlen(s)-1]=='\n' ) s[strlen(s)-1]=0;
  errno=0;
  intValue= strtoul(s,&e,16);
  if( *e || errno==EINVAL || errno==ERANGE )
    puts("error");    
  else
    printf("intValue=0x%04x\n", intValue);
```

If you don't specify a base, it can read in plain integer, hex if it's prefixed with 0x, and octal too if you have a leading zero (but most people forget about that and I have run into issues where people have put in leading zeros for formatting and it's screwed up conversions)